# Does MDA support Cordova hooks?

Tags: cordova, hook, visual-studio-cordova

My quick reading of `vs-mda/app.js` and its dependencies indicates no, but I'm hoping to be proven wrong. I'd like to be able to simply add a `hooks` folder to my MDA project and have its contents copied to the dynamically-generated Cordova project at build-time.

Comment: could you email the team at multidevicehybridapp@microsoft.com, we'd love to hear more about your specific use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Multi-Device Hybrid Apps does not currently support Cordova hooks.

Comment: I'm going to email you with specifics, but I was able to add support for hooks with minimal mods to app.js and lib/util.js.

Comment: @lencharest would be nice if you could share those with rest of us here, or with an external link.

Comment: The code I wrote to support hooks was written against the first CTP of MDA (now VS Tools for Apache Cordova). So it is extremely out of date and not worth sharing.