# How to define global variables, based on config (debug/release)?

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps

How to define global variables for Multi-Device Hybrid Apps, based on config (debug/release/distribution)?

Example: my app have to query (HTTP POST, using ajax) web server. When debugging, i wish to query local web server, when building release config, i wish to query production web server.

**UPD:**
**Avani** adviced to use [Cordova Hooks](http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/), but: 1) looks like hooks not implemented in MDHA ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706618/does-mda-support-cordova-hooks)), and 2) if implemented, where to store hooks? `\project_dir\hooks` or `\project_dir\bld\Debug\hooks`, or some other place or method? MDHA docs are missing.

I tried to add hook to `\project_dir\hooks\after_prepare` (it modifies `index.html`), and got compilation error:

```
EPERM, operation not permitted 'C:\Temp\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\bld\Debug\_www'
```

Comment: Nothing that #if could not do.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Never used it before. Can you point me to good manual?

Comment: Well, but I don't know, where to us #if in MDHA... Project written in JS and HTML. In config.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since configuration is a build-time property, the only way to get its value in to your source code is to generate the source code at build-time. This means creating a template in a templating language like [T4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx), and then hacking your project file to expand the template and generate the desired source code. I recommend the [Clarius.TransformOnBuild](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Clarius.TransformOnBuild/) package for triggering code generation at build-time.

Compile-time directives like `#if` do not exist in Javascript or HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Cordova hooks](http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/) to do that.

Comment: Good idea, but, as mentioned in this topic (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706618/does-mda-support-cordova-hooks), hooks currently not supported :(